# When is WAIT_ABANDONED_0 Returned

Tags: multithreading, winapi, wait

I have code like the following...

```
 HANDLE event = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);
 // pass event to thread which will SetEvent(event);
 DWORD dwResult = MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, &event, 3 * 1000, QS_ALLEVENTS, 0);
```

Is it even possible for MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx to return WAIT_ABANDONED_0 in this scenario?
What types of objects can be "abandoned"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is described in the MSDN docs for [WaitForSingleObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Only a mutex can cause this error condition.  It indicates that the thread that acquired the mutex terminated without explicitly releasing it by calling ReleaseMutex().  That's a pretty gross error condition, something is fairly majorly borked and you should hit the Big Red Emergency Stop button when this happens.  It is almost never *just* the mutex that's in a bad state, whatever other shared program state was touched by that thread is highly likely to be inconsistent as well.